# Get back the whole JSON request from google action with Node js client library

Tags: javascript, node.js, actions-on-google

I am using actions-on-goolge library for nodejs https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google

How would I able to get the whole JSON response, or use id string inside my intent function? I have tried to print out the input, it only gives the query part of the JSON. Tried to look up their documentation, it does not seem to explain how I could get back the whole JSON file.
https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/lib-v1-migration
I am beginner of javascript.

The JSON request from simulator:

```
{
  "user": {
    "userId": "ABwppHEAPgcgb2yFUFURYFEJGg4VdAVcL9UKO9cS7a7rVfasdasdt67LzgrmMseTvb5mmJjbjj7UV",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "lastSeen": "2018-05-11T23:14:42Z",
    "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "conversationId": "1526080586367",
    "type": "NEW"
  },
  "inputs": [
    {
      "intent": "com.example.device.OFF",
      "rawInputs": [
        {
          "inputType": "KEYBOARD",
          "query": "Talk to MyDevice to turn off"
        }
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "name": "trigger_query",
          "rawText": "turn off",
          "textValue": "turn off"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "surface": {
    "capabilities": [
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
      }
    ]
  },
  "isInSandbox": true,
  "availableSurfaces": [
    {
      "capabilities": [
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
        },
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My Node JS script base on the example:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const {
  actionssdk,
  Image,
} = require('actions-on-google')

app.intent('actions.intent.TEXT', (conv, input) => {
  if (input === 'bye' || input === 'goodbye') {
    return conv.close('See you later!')
  }
  conv.ask(`I didn't understand. Can you tell me something else?`)
})

app.intent('com.example.MyDevice.TEST', (conv, input) => {
  console.log(input); 
  console.log(conv.action);
  console.log(conv.intent);
  conv.close('Test Done');
});

express().use(bodyParser.json(), app).listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the entire JSON request through `conv.body`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. How do you get this info? I cannot seem to find it in google docs.

Comment: I knew it already, but the documentation is also shown [here](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/dialogflow.dialogflowconversation.html#body).